# SVG does not show up on Firefox but does on Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, svg, d3.js

On [this page](http://bl.ocks.org/musically-ut/5278601), the SVG elements do not show up in Firefox, but they are displayed in Chrome correctly. The program used to generate the `svg` is present on the page.

The elements are present in the HTML and have the `correct` dimensions and location when viewed via Firebug.

[image]

I am at a loss as to how to explain the discrepancy. Can someone offer any hypothesis?

I am using Firefox 24.0 and Chrome Version 29.0.1547.65

**Update**: This seems to be fixed in Firefox 25.0 The text rendering has also improved!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your SVG element is not sized properly (and overflow is set to hidden) so the content is not shown. You can solve it by specifying the unit in your css:

```
min-height: 600px; /* instead of 600 */
```

Comment: I have made the change on the page. However, still the SVG doesn't show up.

Comment: Sorry, I missed your comment. It seems to be solved now (from the link)?

Comment: Yup, though I suspect upgrading to Firefox 25 had a part to play in it.